# sheet does not dismiss on swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
```

I know just toggle State variable of 'fullScreenCover' or 'sheet' but I found another approach and both above doesn't work.

Here's simple code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var sheetState = false
    @State private var value = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(value)
        
            Button("Present Sheet") {
                sheetState.toggle()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetState) {
            Button("set1") {
                value = "1"
                //presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I press the button of sheet named 'set1' it change the 'value' set '1' and Text of VStack set "1" correctly but sheet doesn't dismiss.
It absolutely same both approach.
Am I using these things wrong?

here's my result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMLfS.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you are trying to dismiss `ContentView` which makes no sense.

You have to create a separate `View` struct for the sheet.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sheetState = false
    @State private var value = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(value)
            
            Button("Present Sheet") {
                sheetState.toggle()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetState) {
            SheetView(value: $value)
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView : View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @Binding var value : String
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("set1") {
            value = "1"
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```